Run expensive operation in the background without awaiting a result
I have done my research on the topic, but I still do not fully understand the async and await blocks in C# as a lot of people suggest different functions and approaches. Still, I can't find anything close to what my goal is.
I am working in Unity and want to send some screenshots over a socket to another application. Unity requires the screenshot to be taken by the main thread, as it is not thread-safe. The costly operation is the sending of the frame, which I though should be better handled by a background thread. This is done in a while(running) loop.
Maybe the easiest way is to just create a new Thread and pass the frame for processing there, but I wanted to know if there is an efficient way to do this with async Task.
First I tried to create an async Task, but I leant that without the await the code is not really parallel. The issue I am facing is, that I do not want the main thread to block and do not require any result from the Task to continue.
This is the final code I am using:
private static async Task sendSceenshot(PushSocket socket, byte[] frame)
{
  await Task.Run(() => socket.TrySendFrame(frame));
}

private static void Screenshot()
{
  while (isRunning)
    {
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
      
      // Take the screenshot...
      // [...]
 
      // Send the frame in the background without blocking the main thread
      sendSceenshot(screenSocketWide, currentFrame);

      // Reset and prepare for next frame
      // [...]
}


with Unity I would generally recommend UniTask where you would simply use a .Forget(); to allow it to run asynchronous ... at least until Awaitable is established enough ;)

Are you doing this "on request", or in every frame (update)? There are async image operations, but the benefits depend on the context; e.g. lazy loading. You might have to queue under other circumstances.

@GerrySchmitz I need to send a screenshot every half a second. I do this with a Coroutine in Unity. I have tried using an AsyncGPURead, but this did not work as expected :( Do you have any other suggestions?

You can just use the Task.Run() method for this. It utilizes the thread pool for you, so you don't have to deal with threads by hand.
private static void Screenshot()
    {
        
        //set up socket and frame
        
        //the key part
        await Task.Run(() => socket.TrySendFrame(frame));
    }

See this to understand the differences between Thread and Task more in depth.
I'm not sure what you meant by "this does not terminate the program", could you elaborate?

Okay, but is this really asynchronous or does the main thread have to wait until the task is done to move on to the next frame?

And the function should be defined as aync, right? Error: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

it is asynchronous, the main thread does not have to wait. To quote the docs:
"[Task.Run] queues the specified work to run on the thread pool and returns a proxy for the task"

Yes, it should be async, as only those methods can be awaited.

as you're not awaiting the function anyway, you can also omit the await from Task.Run.

Unfortunately I am not seeing any significant performance improvements from this. The FPS of the game are still very low as sending them from the main thread. Thank anyways tho!
